# Perl: How to encode and decode characters in uppercase alpha letters only

Tags: regex, perl, encoding, character-encoding, decoding

im dealing with that quite some time now. I have characters from lets say the Latin alphabet and want them to be encoded in uppercase alpha strings only. Is there any module that could do this? Or any BaseX encoding that i can modify to just use uc alpha characters?

i currently have implemented parts of it using regex substitutions, but it only covers a few characters and is definetly not efficient :)

anyway if there is no way to deal with that via a module or function, 
is there any way to do this efficient via a regex?

i thought about a `tr/[\+,\-,...]/[PLUS,MINUS,...]/cds;`

but it seems like tr only substitutes char by char and not char by sequence of chars :(

any ideas?

achim

Comment: your question is a little confusing.  Please give expected input and output data to help us answer your question.

Comment: okay to clarify  a bit: I expect any existing character, special character as input and want them encoded so that the ouput just contains the 26 uppercase alpha characters.

Comment: Can you please explain WHY you're doing it? It smells of XY problem to me (e.g. you're asking how to implement solution X to a problem Y whereas you should ask "how do I solve problem Y" instead). Sometimes, a different solution might be a better answer for such things.

Comment: Well it is not :) my point is:
I implemented a algorithm that simulates enigma dechiffre engine from world war II, which at the end only takes 26 characters. To use that algorithm with more than the 26 characters i need to encode the input first. That's why :)

Comment: So if you have a digit in your string, what would your expected output be? or if you have a character with an accent, or a punctuation symbol? Should the encoding be lossless or can it be lossy: if you decode, should it give back the exact same string, or is just the characters enough?

Comment: Yes after decoding the output should be exactly the same as if was before encoding. For Example: We've got the input String `aB cDeFg!"§$\n` the encoded output should be anythin like this `JEFJHSDHEJHSHDHSH` crypted via the enigma algo would result in anything like this `HJJSFKSFKSHFHSJJH` ->decrypted `JEFJHSDHEJHSHDHSH` ->decoded `aB cDeFg!"§$\n`

I think the way to go is use a Base26 encoding ikegami hab implemented below. Sry for the imprecise explanation, was my first question :-|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the `tr` question:

```
%subs = ( '+' => 'PLUS' );
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %subs;
s/($pat)/$subs{$1}/g;
```

Base 26 is possible to do, but it's a bit hard and inefficient to implement since 26 is not a power of 2. But it's definitely what you want. I'll see about coding it up.

In the meantime, here's a base 16 solution:

```
sub bytes_to_base16 {
   my $e = unpack('H*', $_);
   $e =~ tr/0123456789ABCDEFabcdef/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPKLMNOP/;
   return $e;
}

sub base16_to_bytes {
   my $e = $_[0];
   $e =~ tr/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP/0123456789ABCDEF/;
   return pack('H*', $_);
}
```

---

Let's see how efficient base 26 is compared to base 16:

```
$ perl -MMath::BigInt -MMath::BigFloat -E'
   my $n = Math::BigInt->new(1);
   my $bs = 0;
   for (1..10) {
      $n <<= 8;
      ++$bs;
      my $bd16 = 2*$bs;
      my $bd26 = Math::BigFloat->new($n)->blog(26, 5)->bceil->numify;
      say sprintf "%2d bytes takes %2d base16 digits or %2d base26 digits.".
                  " base26 is %3.0f%% of the size of base16.",
         $bs, $bd16, $bd26, $bd26/$bd16*100;
      }
'
 1 bytes takes  2 base16 digits or  2 base26 digits. base26 is 100% of the size of base16.
 2 bytes takes  4 base16 digits or  4 base26 digits. base26 is 100% of the size of base16.
 3 bytes takes  6 base16 digits or  6 base26 digits. base26 is 100% of the size of base16.
 4 bytes takes  8 base16 digits or  7 base26 digits. base26 is  88% of the size of base16.
 5 bytes takes 10 base16 digits or  9 base26 digits. base26 is  90% of the size of base16.
 6 bytes takes 12 base16 digits or 11 base26 digits. base26 is  92% of the size of base16.
 7 bytes takes 14 base16 digits or 12 base26 digits. base26 is  86% of the size of base16.
 8 bytes takes 16 base16 digits or 14 base26 digits. base26 is  88% of the size of base16.
 9 bytes takes 18 base16 digits or 16 base26 digits. base26 is  89% of the size of base16.
10 bytes takes 20 base16 digits or 18 base26 digits. base26 is  90% of the size of base16.
```

An efficient implementation would produce slightly less efficient output.

```
$ perl -MMath::BigInt -MMath::BigFloat -E'
   my $bs = 0;
   for (1..10) {
      ++$bs;
      my $bd16 = 2*$bs;
      my $bd26 = int($bs/4)*7 + ($bs%4)*2;
      say sprintf "%2d bytes takes %2d base16 digits or %2d base26 digits.".
                  " base26 is %3.0f%% of the size of base16.",
         $bs, $bd16, $bd26, $bd26/$bd16*100;
      }
'
 1 bytes takes  2 base16 digits or  2 base26 digits. base26 is 100% of the size of base16.
 2 bytes takes  4 base16 digits or  4 base26 digits. base26 is 100% of the size of base16.
 3 bytes takes  6 base16 digits or  6 base26 digits. base26 is 100% of the size of base16.
 4 bytes takes  8 base16 digits or  7 base26 digits. base26 is  88% of the size of base16.
 5 bytes takes 10 base16 digits or  9 base26 digits. base26 is  90% of the size of base16.
 6 bytes takes 12 base16 digits or 11 base26 digits. base26 is  92% of the size of base16.
 7 bytes takes 14 base16 digits or 13 base26 digits. base26 is  93% of the size of base16.
 8 bytes takes 16 base16 digits or 14 base26 digits. base26 is  88% of the size of base16.
 9 bytes takes 18 base16 digits or 16 base26 digits. base26 is  89% of the size of base16.
10 bytes takes 20 base16 digits or 18 base26 digits. base26 is  90% of the size of base16.
```

Note that the efficient implementation uses an extra digits for inputs that are 7 bytes long.

So is it worth the effort of using base26 over base16? Probably not, unless each byte is *really* precious.

---

And finally, here's a base 26 implementation.

```
my @syms = ('A'..'Z');
my %syms = map { $syms[$_] => $_ } 0..$#syms;

sub bytes_to_base26 {
   my $e = '';

   my $full_blocks = int(length($_[0]) / 4);
   for (0..$full_blocks-1) {
      my $block = unpack('N', substr($_[0], $_*4, 4));
      $e .= join '', @syms[
         $block / 26**6 % 26,
         $block / 26**5 % 26,
         $block / 26**4 % 26,
         $block / 26**3 % 26,
         $block / 26**2 % 26,
         $block / 26**1 % 26,
         $block / 26**0 % 26,
      ];
   }

   my $extra = substr($_[0], $full_blocks*4);
   for my $block (unpack('C*', $extra)) {
      $e .= join '', @syms[
         $block / 26**1 % 26,
         $block / 26**0 % 26,
      ];
   }

   return $e;
}

sub base26_to_bytes {
   my $d = '';

   my $full_blocks = int(length($_[0]) / 7);
   for (0..$full_blocks-1) {
      my $block = 0;
      $block = $block*26 + $syms{$_} for unpack '(a)*', substr($_[0], $_*7, 7);
      $d .= pack('N', $block);
   }

   my $extra = substr($_[0], $full_blocks*7);
   my @extra = unpack('(a)*', $extra);
   while (@extra) {
      my $block = 0;
      $block = $block*26 + $syms{ shift(@extra) };
      $block = $block*26 + $syms{ shift(@extra) };
      $d .= pack('C', $block);
   }

   return $d;
}
```

Comment: @achim, Added base 16 solution.

Comment: @achim. Added base 25 efficiency analysis.

Comment: Base26 isn't impossible at all, you just need to use multiple symbols for efficiency. For example, you can encode 7 bytes in 12 base26 symbols *if you encode them all at once* (which means you need 64-bit arithmetic). It's totally doable, but not very worthwhile in such a low base. Base85, on the other hand, makes good use of it.

Comment: @achim, Finally, Added a base 26 implementation. Turns out base 26 is possible -- I forgot that base64 doesn't actually need "=" -- and it's not really any harder to implement than base that's a power of 2.

Comment: @hobbs, Well, it's not truly base 26, but yes, it's possible to use 26 symbols. I forgot that base64 doesn't actually need to use the 65th symbols it uses. I've already corrected and added an implementation. I'm encoding 4 bytes in 7, which produced optimum efficiency except for 7-byte strings, and that just needs 32-bit math.

Comment: Thanks ikegami this is very helpful! The point y i cant use a base16 is because i would waste 10 characters weakening the encryption method enormously. And since encrypting in an world war 2 algorithm isn't very efficient, the encoding to do this does not have to be very efficient at all :) i currently implemented a base32 encoding using 25letters and 7digits which afterwards re encodes the digits identified by the 26th letter. But the Base26 implementation u posted is much better. Thousand thanks for your great efforts!

Comment: @achim, Two comments: First, an unused character value does not translate to a wasted character. As I showed, for 10 bytes, base 16 only wastes 2 more character than base 25 (10 instead of 8). Secondly, not using all possible character values does not weaken the encryption.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is to use base16 encoding, as others have suggested, and remap the digits to letters -- but then you're only using 16 out of 26 characters, which is wasteful.

The most efficient possible encoding would be base26, but that would be very difficult -- in effect you'd be treating the entire input as a large binary number and converting it from base 2 to base 26.

log2(26) is just over 4.7, so at best (in the absence of compression) you can encode 4.7 bits per letter.  A less wasteful encoding might encode 4 bytes (32 bits) in 7 letters.  7 letters gives you about 32.9 bits of information, so you're not losing as much information.  And it can all be done in 32-bit arithmetic.  Then you'll have to decide what to do if the input isn't a multiple of 4 bytes.

(The actual implementation is left as an exercise -- at least for now.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Base32 encoding, with 26 uppercase letters and 6 digits:

[`http://pastebin.com/YPvfrpHW`](http://pastebin.com/YPvfrpHW)

Just change the `$code` array to whatever charset you want to use.

Edit: Whoops, just noticed you're Perl and not PHP, sorry. You should be able to find a Base32 module on CPAN that does the same thing.

Edit 2: FWIW, I see Convert::Base32, Encode::Base32, and MIME::Base32 on CPAN.

Comment: Thanks, i saw that too. The only Problem left is that i cannot use digits at all :( So i thought about reencoding the digits manually, which isnt much elegant at all (and not save), or use a Base16 wich wastes 10 characters... any better idea?

Comment: Yeah, base26 is what needs to be done. Convert your string to an integer. Encode this integer in base 26.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

For a bit of fun, here's my Enigma simulator. There isn't an easy way to achieve what you want to do as the wheels don't have any escape chars, and any sequences you invent to represent an escape sequence will significantly reduce the strength of the cipher.

However, 8 bit latin input could be mapped from 0-255 to [A-P][A-P] using 65+($Char&15).65+($Char>>4), and reversed on output, but R-Z would be wasted and there would be a lot of holes in the input, though this could be solved running through gzip first.

The Germans usually used X to represent spaces, and spelled out punctuation if really necessary, trying to avoid spelling the same thing twice the same.
I know it is annoying, but that is the way it is. If we increase the number of letters on the wheels, then it ceases to be an Enigma machine!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#Tinigma 2010 Usage:tinigma.pl 123 rng ini "GHWVYYDVPQGEWQWVT"
($n,$o,$p)=map(ord()-65,split//,uc$ARGV[1]);($z,$y,$x)=map(ord
()-65,split//,uc$ARGV[2]);($l,$m,$r)=map$_-1,split//,$ARGV[0];
$t=uc$ARGV[3];$t=~s/[^A-Z]//g;$b=26;$j=0;@N=qw(7 25 11 6 1);@R
=('EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ'x3,'AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE'x
3,'BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO'x3,'ESOVPZJAYQUIRHXLNFTGKDCMWB'x
3,'VZBRGITYUPSDNHLXAWMJQOFECK'x3,'YRUHQSLDPXNGOKMIEBFZCWVJAT'x
3);@t=split//,$t;for$v(@R){$i=0;for(split//,$v){$c=ord($_)-65;
$F[$j][$i]=$c;$R[$j][$c+$b*(int($i/$b))]=$i;$i++}$j++}@S=@{$F[
5]};$f=$y==$F[$m][$N[$m]]?1:0;$i=0;for(@t){if($f){$y++;$y%=$b;
$z++;$z%=$b;$f=0}if($x==$F[$r][$N[$r]]){$y++;$y%=$b;if($y==$F[
$m][$N[$m]]){$f=1}}$x++;$x%=$b;$e.=chr(($R[$r][$R[$m][$R[$l][$
S[$F[$l][$F[$m][$F[$r][ord($_)-39+$x-$n]-$x+$n+$y-$o]-$y+$o+$z
-$p]-$z+$p]+$z-$p]-$z+$p+$y-$o]-$y+$o+$x-$n]-$x+$n)%$b+65)}
print"$e\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

*This solution was already briefly mentioned by [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098277/6770384) and [jrockway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095527/perl-how-to-encode-and-decode-characters-in-uppercase-alpha-letters-only/63386243#comment8499570_7095646).

Here we look into it and implement it.*

---

The problem is very simple if you know that:

- Any file (binary or text) can be seen as one big number.
  Think of the file's bytes as the digits of a number in a base 2<sup>8</sup> = 256.
- Any number can be converted to any natural base N ≥ 2.
- The N digits for representing a number in base N can be chosen freely.
  Usually we use `0`, `1`, `2`, … but its possible to use `A`, `B`, `C`, … or even , , , … instead.

Therefore, an approach to encode your (text) file using only `A`-`Z` is:

- Read the file as one big number F.
- Print F in base 26 using the digits `A`-`Z`.

Here's an implementation:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt try => 'GMP';

our $plaintextDigits = join('', map(chr, 0..255));
our $codeDigits = join('', 'A'..'Z');

sub baseConversion {
  my ($str, $inDigits, $outDigits) = @_;
  return Math::BigInt
    ->from_base($str, length $inDigits, $inDigits)
    ->to_base(length $outDigits, $outDigits);
}

sub encode {
  return baseConversion shift, $main::plaintextDigits, $main::codeDigits;
}

sub decode {
  return baseConversion shift, $main::codeDigits, $main::plaintextDigits;
}

my $input = 'String to be encoded. Or use `shift` to read an CLI argument.';
print "input:\n$input\n";
my $encoded = encode $input;
print "\nencoded:\n$encoded\n";
my $decoded = decode $encoded;
print "\ndecoded:\n$decoded\n";
```

This prints the encoding `ESQEKWWQLSBQHVKBCAQYKLXMVQRUFOOMPJGFTADLYTDQLFGTRTLWJBYTJICKUOFUVPHSHZHCRZKFMVSHRHCACZFUWTXVXUDRVKMIAIKK` which is then decoded correctly again.

**Benefits:**

- The encoded text is as space efficient as can be. The only way to get a shorter encoding is to compress the input before encoding it.
- In theory, encoding and decoding are very simple as they are only base conversions.

**Drawbacks:**

- Conversion is not very efficient

  - The file has to fit into memory.
  - The time complexity of conversion is super-linear in the size of the input. Since 26 is not a power of 2 we have to divide the input number (having the size of the file!) for each output digit.
    However, in practice this probably is acceptable as I suspect you only deal with rather short strings. On my system (i5-4570, 3.2 GHz), the very un-optimized implementation from above instantly encoded and decoded 1 kB. Without GMP 10 kB took 11 seconds. With GMP 100 kB took 10 seconds.

**Implementation Notes:**

- For simplicity I made some assumptions on the input's and perl's internal string representation (which may differ between systems). For a more robust solution you should use perl's `utf8::encode`/`decode` on the input and `our $...Digits`.
- `from_base` and `to_base` could probably be implemented more efficiently because the default implementation might not know that the digits `$...Digits` are continuous.

Answer (score -1):

Base64 encoding generates hexadecimal output, meaning 16 possible characters. Because the alphabet has 26, you could possibly swap digits with numbers. You'll then use just 16 characters of the alphabet, but you'd have a string consisting of just alphabetic letters where it's really easy to encode-decode and get the original string back. It's a strange question (and it looks like homework assignment) but it will do the trick.

Comment: Total nonsense! Base64 generates base-64 output, over 64 characters [a-zA-Z0-9+/].

Comment: Yeah absolutely, I'm sorry, I meant hex-encoding.

Answer (score -2):

You've specced a very lossy translation... which may not be satisfactory.

But:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl  
    use strict;  
    use warnings;  
    use 5.012;  

    # 7095527/perl-how-to-encode-and-decode-characters-in-uppercase-alpha-letters-only  

    my $string = "abcDEFghijklMNO1234567890pqr+_)!@#}{?";  
    my @arr = split //, uc($string);  

    my (@intermediate, $char);  
    for my $char(@arr) {  
        if ($char =~ /[A-Z]/) {  
            say "ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): $char";  
        } else {  
            say "WTF? \$char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: $char";  
            next;  
        }  
    }  

    =head OUTPUT:  

    > SO7095527.pl  
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): A
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): B
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): C
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): D
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): E
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): F
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): G
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): H
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): I
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): J
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): K
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): L
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): M
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): N
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): O
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 1
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 2
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 3
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 4
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 5
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 6
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 7
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 8
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 9
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: 0
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): P
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): Q
    ENIGMA char found (possibly uc'ed): R
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: +
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: _
    WTF? $char at line17 is !~ /[A-Z]/: )
    ...

    =cut
```

Note that the submarine captain is going to get useless direction if the message specifies the refueling location as "73N 39W"...